# Why random margins between HTML Div tags

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to fill the data in div tag using angularJS loop.

```
<div>
    <div class='box' ng-repeat="product in Products | filter:{'scid': SCId.toString()}:true | orderBy:'pname'">
        <br>
        <b>{{product.bname}}  </b>
        <br>{{ product.pname }}
        <br>
        <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.image_path }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS Class.

```
.box {
margin : 5px;
display : inline-block;
width: 150px;
height: 250px;
background-color: grey;
text-align:center;
}
```

But its not rendering properly. (some random margin top and bottom)

[image]

Can someone help what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your CSS

Answer (score 4):

1. This is due to `vertical-align: middle`
   always add `vertical-align: top;` with `display: inline-block;`
2. Second problem is unknown margins, `display: inline-block;` elements get margin, add `font-size: 0` to its parent. :)

```css
ul {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because `display:inline-block`, is by default set to `vertical-align:baseline`, so you need to set `vertical-align:top`.

> An element set to `inline-block` is very similar to `inline` in that it
>   will set `inline` with the natural flow of text (on the "`baseline`"). The
>   difference is that you are able to set a `width` and `height` which will
>   be respected.

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Plus `display:inline-block` causes gap between elements, which there are a few solutions to fix them:

- Remove the spaces
- Negative margin
- Skip the closing tag
- Set the font size to zero

[Read more](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

so here is a snippet:

```css
.box-wrapper {
  font-size: 0
}
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">this will be vertical aligned top</div>
  <div class="box">this will be vertical aligned top</div>
  <div class="box">this will be vertical aligned top</div>
</div>
```